# set onclicklistener for button inside customlistview android

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I am using baseadapter  to create a custom listview. My listview contains textview, two buttons and an edittext. The two buttons are for addition and subtraction. when I click on plus button I want the value in edittext to be incremented by 1 and I have kept default value for edittext as 1.

This is the getView method in mycustombaseadapter for listview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        int i=1;
        if (convertView == null) {


       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.each_menu, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();


      holder.txtoutletname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuname);
      holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);
      holder.plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusbut);
      holder.minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusbut);
      holder.qua = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quanedit);
      holder.plus.setId(i);

      holder.minus.setId(i); 
      i++;
       convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      holder.txtoutletname.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getmenuname());
      holder.price.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getcost());




      holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 String vall=holder.qua.getText().toString();
                 int num=Integer.parseInt(vall);
                 num=num+1;
                 holder.qua.setText(num);
                 Log.d("plus",vall);

            }
        });





      return convertView;

}
```

This is the ViewHolder class

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtoutletname; 
    TextView price;
    NumberPicker np;
    Button plus;
    Button minus;
    EditText qua;

    }
```

Now when I click on + button the activity is forced close.
please help me to get this.

String.valueOf() worked for me.
thanks

but now as the button are clickable the listview is not clickable..
I want the buton as well as listview both should be clickable.
I have added the itemclicklistener which is working without those buttons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
holder.qua.setText(num);
```

by

```
holder.qua.setText(String.valueOf(num));
```

coz you have this

```
int num=Integer.parseInt(vall); // num is an int value
num=num+1;
```

`public final void setText (int resid)`

In your case it looks for a resource with the id. If not found you get ResourceNotFoundException.

What you need

`public final void setText (CharSequence text)` which takes `CharSequence` as param.

So use `String.valueOf(num)`

Comment: This is the correct answer, it's a very common mistake, if you want to show a number in a TextView you have to use String.valueOf(), otherwise it will call setText(int resId)